# New Apache Server - Trouble with .htaccess

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, lamp

(Pardon me, I've injured my right hand so I'll have trouble typing)

I've recently set up a new Linux server running off the 'LAMP Stack'. I used PuTTY, Git and friends. Usually, I work in a pre-set up environment - I'm just an app developer. This would technically count as my first 'solo venture'. I've never been given root access to a server before, I was just there to work.

So, to get started, I decided to port some of my work from a previous project and build off of that. It relies heavily on **`Rewrite`** Rules. Ignorantly, I assumed my .htaccess file would magically work. It doesn't - For whatever reason, Apache wants you to enable the use of rewrite rules (It's not like you'd accidentally set up an .htaccess file, dear me).

So, I've read various tutorials, followed guides, asked elsewhere - I'm not really getting anywhere. To finally get to the point, here's what I've done:

**1.** I enable the use of .htaccess files at /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf:

```
 <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
 </Directory>
```

**2**. I create an .htaccess file at **var/www/html/site**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/index.php [L]
```

**3**. Now, you should be able to reach a URL located at **http://www.example.com/site/index.php/Bool** via **http://www.example.com/Bool** (**Bool** is something like a query string - A page identifier). You can't in this case - You're told that there's no file titled '**Bool**' on the server.

The rewrite rules given in section **2** have worked before, but don't work here.

Some guides also tell you to do wacky stuff like set up some password system at **`/etc/htaccess/.htpasswd`** and have another .htaccess file to call on that or something. Despite my other rewrite rules not working in this new server environment, the 'password' system did actually work (I was asked to provide a password before accessing a page) - However, I don't need or want any restricted access pages like that.

Practically everything I've tried has not worked - And that's ranged from changing the path in the **`<Directory>`** tag within **`default-ssl.conf`** to putting .htaccess files here and there, with and without password systems, different 'code' in the .htaccess/configuration files, and more. Practically every 'guide' provides you with a different solution, including and excluding details and steps others do/don't.

I've even attempted changing **`AllowOverride`** to **`All`** in **`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`** to no success - Just an **Internal Server Error**.

The grand question: **How do you enable the use of .htaccess files anywhere you need them?** Somebody has to be using a correct configuration somewhere, so you happen to have that working on your server, I'd like to see what you did.

I'm very excited to be in charge of my own server,  it's been a wonderful learning experience and surprisingly, the learning curve hasn't been too difficult. I hope I can get this app running on it properly.

Comment: If you get an internal server error, the first thing you should do is check the server’s error log …

Answer (score 0):

If Unfortunately Your HtAccess File are not being read by your server even in any case then you can use this command in order to enable the htaccess accessibity onto your server.

**TO ENABLE HTACCESS FILE ON RACKSPACE SERVER(Debian Os)**
**sudo a2enmod rewrite**

and restart the apache server now it will be accessible.
Thanks
Raghwendra Pathak